# How to raise exception in except block without original traceback in python 3.5+

Tags: python, python-3.x, exception

Library code can raise custom library exception; I would like to catch that one and raise my own exception without original exception and original traceback information attached:

```
    try:
        can_raise_custom_lib_exception()
    except custom_lib_exception as e:
        cleanup()
        raise myOwnException("my own extra text")
```

In this way original exception is thrown (with traceback), message:

> During handling of the above exception, another exception occured:

is displayed followed by  `MyOwnException` (with traceback).

Is it possible to hide original exception and display my exception only? It looks like python 3.5+ attaches the traceback information to the error and I would like to completely hide the first one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `raise from None` to suppress earlier exceptions:

```
try:
    can_raise_custom_lib_exception()
except custom_lib_exception as e:
    cleanup()
    raise myOwnException("my own extra text") from None
```

> #### [7.8. The raise statement](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#raise)
>
> [...]
> Exception chaining can be explicitly suppressed by specifying `None` in the `from` clause: